# angularjs push data into ng-repeat object after posting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my code

```
<select class="form-control" id="prevCountry" name="prevCountry" ng-model="asset.assets.countryID" ng-options="value.ID as value.country for value in technical.country">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
```

angularjs code

$scope.technical.assets.push($scope.assets);

I'm posting countryID but I want to push into ng-repeat object the countryName of countryID.

Comment: Please be more specific and provide a plunkr of what you've done so far

Comment: Please give enough content. and question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need to check the example of ngOptions usage [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSqtJFmRG4DKRLvwg5MW?p=preview) for you. Hope it'll help.

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.countryName for option in technical.country"
  ng-model="asset.assets"></select>
```